# Libmemached lagging not getting the cache value from the server after memcached rebooted

Tags: php, memcached, phalcon, libmemcached

Am using phalcon libmemcached my php application. Once i deleted and recreate the memcache server after that i can set the token in the cache it is working and also i can get the token from the cache server immediately. But when i use the same token in another endpoint for authentication process the token is not getting from cache its return null. Same token working as expected after 5 min. I checked below command in terminal and token still in the cache

php -r '$c = new Memcached(); $c->addServer("my server name", port);

var_dump( $c->getAllKeys() );'

Some one please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is not persistence. All data is lost on reboot.

Comment: Once recreated after that also libmemcached not get the token from cache. But token was set